# How to set css position 'top' relative to document height instead of viewport height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I will try to make my question more clear.

Because I used below setting on Html body, I need to scroll the page down to get to page bottom.

```
body {  height: 180vh;}
```

And I want to set a div position `top` property relative to document height, so that I can control its position at a place only visible when I scroll down. I prefer to set it by percentage value so that code will adapt different sizes of devices.

But by default the `top` property is relative to viewport, so I can not realize it by setting `top` value.

Is there a way to realize what I want to do? even not by `top` property.

Comment: You can do it by bottom: 0; if it helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give the body a `position: relative` and the div a `position: absolute`, you can set the `top` property as a percentage, where `top: 100%` will position it at the bottom of the page:

```css
body {  
  height: 180vh;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

div{
   height: 30px;
   width: 140px;
   border: solid 2px gray;
   background: white;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly, there are 2 ways

- use `padding-top`
- use `position:absolute` and `top`

code **snippet** below:

```css
body {
  height: 180vh;
}

.myDiv1 {
  margin-top: 110vh;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.myDiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150vh;
  height: 100px;
  width: 98%;
  background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='myDiv1'></div>
  <div class='myDiv2'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that the `position` property of the body is `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.
You can then set the `position: absolute` to make the element be dependent on the last parent element that had one of three properties mentioned above. 
Finally you can set your `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` properties after that.

```css
body {
  height: 180vh;
  position: relative;
}

#down {
  position: absolute;
  // or bottom: 10%;
  bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="down">Here</div>
```